# Signals and slots in QT Designer

Tags: python, qt5

I'm trying to use the auto generated code from QT designer and converting it to py code with pyuic5.
Works fine so far as I get the py code to display the ui file just fine.

I'm trying to get a signal from a button.
I have created an Action in the Action editor called "actionOn_click"

This is the auto generated code for the button:

```
self.btnTestData1.clicked.connect(self.actionOn_click.trigger)
```

only 4 options are available instead of .trigger from within the QT designer. hover(), toggle() and deleteLater().

Am I doing this correctly ?
I have the ui.py code as a separate file as it gets overwritten every-time I make some changes to the user interface (which is quite often)

I have spent hours trawling the net but all the info seems to be either that everything is handwritten from the start or the examples just connect a signal to a slot already within the QT frame work.

Any suggestions ?

I'm using QT designer V5.9.0, pyuic5 (5.8.2) and python 3.6

Thanks